# Backbone.js routing without changing url

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, pushstate, hashbang

I am migrating a single-page web application based on Backbone.js and jQuery to a Chrome extension. However, neither the `pushState` nor the hashbang-based router modes seem to play well with the environment within the extension. I've come to the conclusion that I'm better off just directly rendering views on user interactions, bypassing the `window.location` system altogether. However, I'm not too sure how to implement this without changing calls to `Router.navigate` in dozens of files.

Is there a pluggable/modular way to keep the Backbone routing system but bypass any changes to the url?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I you really want to stick with using `Router.navigate` to benefit from the routing system that Backbone.js provides without having to deal with hashbang bugs when used in a Chrome extension (e.g. routes including a slash being overwritten), you could make `Router.navigate` load the url directly, skipping the whole pushState gymnastic.

This is actually pretty easy to accomplish:

```
Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

  navigate: function (url) {

    // Override pushstate and load url directly
    Backbone.history.loadUrl(url);

  },

  // Put routes here
  routes: { }

});
```

You can then call `Router.navigate(url)` to load a new route without changing history, or even bind the action to every link containing a `data-backbone` attribute (e.g. `<a href="login" data-backbone>Login</a>`) with an event like this:

```
$(function(){

  // Initialize router
  Router = new Router;
  Backbone.history.start();

  // Bind a[data-backbone] to router
  $(document).on('click', 'a[data-backbone]', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    Router.navigate( $(this).attr('href') );
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could redefine what `Router.navigate` does, but you're better off just not using the Background.router altogether.  I think it could create some confusion, and your code will be cleaner without it if you're currently triggering history changes from views.

[Backbone.Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) has a concept of Controllers, which work a lot like routers without a URL-map (with Marionette, the idea is to keep your route definitions minimal, and call controllers for the behavior instead). You also don't need to use any of the components of Marionette you don't want.

If you really wanted to stick with the router as it is, you could probably just redefine `Backbone.History.navigate` to  (note, untested)

```
navigate: function(fragment, options) {
    if (!History.started) return false;
    if (!options || options === true) options = {trigger: options};
    fragment = this.getFragment(fragment || '');
    if (this.fragment === fragment) return;
    this.fragment = fragment;     
    if (options.trigger) this.loadUrl(fragment);
}
```

Comment: AppRouter is what should be used instead of Router.  The Marionette Controller class is now deprecated - any object can serve as a controller for use by an AppRouter.